# Installing python 32-bit to coexist with 64-bit python on a 64-bit machine

Tags: linux, python, redhat-enterprise-linux

How can I install the 32-bit python while leaving the 64-bit one under RHEL7 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installed python 32 bits after 64 bits](http://superuser.com/questions/607031/installed-python-32-bits-after-64-bits)

Comment: that is not a duplicate, the question is targeted for windows. It is in noway similar to linux

Comment: See also [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29253/how-can-i-install-a-32bit-python-on-64-bit-ubuntu) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789519/install-python-32-bit-on-64-bit-linux).

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, because the post referred to is specific to Linux. Please take this under consideration when voting to close.